# How do i match a random number using regex after a particular text in a multi string variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

In python, I want to capture a random number lets say '100000000000000000' by searching for 'Beginning Supply' in a multi string variable as shown below,

```
import re

message = """Test
- 55244
Graph
- Tools
Beginning Supply
- 100000000000000000
Name
- Text2
Type"""

pattern = re.compile(r"Total.Supply...(\d+)")
pattern.match(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `.` does not capture `\n` characters. In order to achieve that you must use the `DOTALL` flag in your pattern.

If you want to use `match`:

```
import re

message = """Test
- 55244
Graph
- Tools
Beginning Supply
- 100000000000000000
Name
- Text2
Type"""

pattern = re.compile(r"(?:.*)(Beginning Supply...)(?P<num>\d+)(?:.*)", flags=re.DOTALL)
number = pattern.match(message).group("num")
```

If you want to use `findall`:

```
import re

message = """Test
- 55244
Graph
- Tools
Beginning Supply
- 100000000000000000
Name
- Text2
Type"""

pattern = re.compile(r"Beginning Supply...(\d+)", flags=re.DOTALL)
number = pattern.findall(message)[0]
```

NOTE: `re.match` must match the entire string or else it will return `None`